# I want to extract multiple data with delimiters in Google Sheets and add it to Docs through tags

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I want to solve an issue regarding Google Sheets and fillable Docs through tags. Thing is, I've already done it right for one customer with one request (ex. one client wants one car quotation) following the instructions in this [site](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data/) resulting in a nice Doc in can share with the client, but what if one client wants multiple cars quotations? My cells in Sheets will be populated with multiple comma separated strings like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZR9I.png). That's why I would like to do the following steps:

- First, split the strings in each cell by eliminating the comma
- Second, add the strings into an array or to a JSON
- Third, extract data from each array into a fillable PDF through tags by following the replace method that Apps Script has

So, I hope that anyone have the time to help me with this as I'm new with programming and also with Google Apps Scripts. Many thanks in advance!

PS: you can watch the result I'm looking for in case that one client wants multiple models in one quotation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS7Dz.jpg). Also, you can search for the Doc template of my quotation model [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x1ADadbUw8vCwMI54XiogfGGg0P05KxWtX_yE2nqgc8/edit?usp=sharing) and the Sheets example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187UqBFQl8XkcBkv2q_c7VPFCYxN8akQCXiLRAH1LqJ8/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Function to add one client's data to a Doc template from Sheets`
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function CreateNewGoogleDocs() {

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('Doc's ID');
  const destinationfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder's ID');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet's Name');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  rows.forEach(function(row,index) {
    if(index === 0) return;
    if(row[10]) return;
 
//Name the file and get its elements
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Quotation ${row[0]}`, destinationfolder);
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
const body = doc.getBody();
const header = doc.getHeader();

//Data conversion  
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[9]).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");

//Currency conversion 
var n1 = new Number(row[6]); //Price
var n2 = new Number(row[6]*0.16); //Tax
var n3 = new Number(n1+n2+350); //Final price

var formatted = {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
};

console.log(formatted);

const friendlyCurrency1 = n1.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)
const friendlyCurrency2 = n2.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)
const friendlyCurrency3 = n3.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)


//Replace data in header   
header.replaceText('{{Quotation}}', row[0]);
   
//Replace general data in the body
body.replaceText('{{Client}}',row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Brand}}',row[2]);
body.replaceText('{{Model}}',row[3]);
body.replaceText('{{Year}}',row[4]);
body.replaceText('{{Date}}',friendlyDate);

//Replace financial data
body.replaceText('{{Price}}',friendlyCurrency1);
body.replaceText('{{Tax}}',friendlyCurrency2);
body.replaceText('{{Final price}}',friendlyCurrency3);

//Save and create Doc's URL
doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index+1,11).setValue(url)

   })  
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide your current code so we can just adjust it to a code with split? it should be easier to understand especially for you if the modifications done was on something you already did.

Comment: Hello there @NaziA. I've updated the post and now you can watch the code for one client requesting one car model. I would like to do it for the case when one client wants multiple cars information. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RichardQuintana, I tried modifying the source code initially. It has some comments on it and you should be able to see the changes there easily. See my answer below. Seeing your code above, it is pretty similar and you should be able to cross check yours with mine

Comment: Hi @RichardQuintana, I have updated the answer below showing the updated code you provided. Kindly check if it works on yours.

Comment: @NaziA many thanks for your help, but thing is that by testing the code you provided and combining it with mine, the result is multiple documents for different clients. As per my request, I'm trying to find a way that I can add multiple car models for one client. You can look for more in the PS I've already updated in the post. Hope you can understand and thanks again!

Comment: Hi @RichardQuintana, can you post a copy of the template that is viewable by public so I could easily replicate your output. If you can also show a single row sample of your sheet data, that would be great.

Comment: @NaziA I've already added the output as a Doc I constructed manually, but I would like to do so with a function that creates a loop, so I can add multiple car models for the same client. I will create a template for you in the meantine

Comment: I'm asking for the template and for the actual row of the data since your sample doc shows existing inventory which I don't know where it gets its value, also other quotations doesnt have colors, some doesn't have brands, some doesnt have tax and final price. It would be better if a sample row is provided, including the template to be processed, and the actual output after processing (containing the sample row provided) so I could actually replicate your output without any unnecessary assumptions. Thanks. :)

Comment: @NaziA I've updated the PS in my post so you can enter both Docs and Sheets templates in order to help me with the request. Please let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly check. Colors and Availability were left out as they were unclear as to how I determine their values per quotation. adjust it if needed.

Comment: Hello there @NaziA thanks for your help.I will try with your updates to see how it works. We'll keep in touch if anything goes by!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code you provided above. See below.

#### Code:

```
// Initialize as global variable for easier access
const googleDocTemplateMain = DriveApp.getFileById('');
const googleDocTemplateTable = DriveApp.getFileById('');
const destinationfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('');
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Function to add one client's data to a Doc template from Sheets`
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function CreateNewGoogleDocs() {
  // Used getDisplayValues for easier parsing
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;

    var quotations;
    // If multiple quotations in a row
    if (row[0].includes(",")) {
      quotations = row[0].split(",");
      // Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link'
      // and has the same number of elements compared to the first column.
      if (row[10] && row[10].split(",").length == quotations.length) return;

      // Remove the values of tax and finalPrice then recalculate
      sheet.getRange(index + 1, 8, 1, 2).clearContent();
      // Split all columns, and access them with index2 inside the forEach loop
      for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (i == 6) {
          row[i] = row[i].substring(1);
          row[i] = row[i].split(",$");
        }
        else 
          row[i] = row[i].split(",");
      }

      // Process each element in the row
      quotations.forEach(function(quotation, index2) {
        var elements = [row[0][index2], row[1][index2], 
                        row[2][index2], row[3][index2],
                        row[4][index2], row[5][index2],
                        row[6][index2], row[7][index2], 
                        row[8][index2], row[9][index2]];
        processSingleQuotation(elements, index);
      });
    }
    else {
      if (row[10]) return;
      // Remove the values of tax and finalPrice then recalculate
      sheet.getRange(index + 1, 8, 1, 2).clearContent();
      processSingleQuotation(row, index);
    }
  });
}

function processSingleQuotation(row, index){
  var copyMain, docMain, copyTable, docTable, bodyTable;
  var filename = `Quotation ${row[0].trim()}`;
  var files = destinationfolder.getFilesByName(filename);

  // If true, then filename already exists
  // Use existing file instead
  if (files.hasNext())
    docMain = DocumentApp.openById(files.next().getId());
  else {
    copyMain = googleDocTemplateMain.makeCopy(`Quotation ${row[0].trim()}`, destinationfolder);
    docMain = DocumentApp.openById(copyMain.getId());
  }
  // Template data for main document
  const bodyMain = docMain.getBody();
  const headerMain = docMain.getHeader();

  // Template data for table
  copyTable = googleDocTemplateTable.makeCopy(`Table ${row[0].trim()}`, destinationfolder);
  docTable = DocumentApp.openById(copyTable.getId());
  bodyTable = docTable.getBody();

  const friendlyDate = new Date(convertDate(row[9].trim())).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");

  var price = formatPrice(row[6].trim());
  
  //Currency conversion 
  var n1 = new Number(price); //Price
  var n2 = new Number(price * 0.16); //Tax
  var n3 = new Number(n1 + n2 + 350); //Final price

  var formatted = {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  };

  const friendlyCurrency1 = n1.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)
  const friendlyCurrency2 = n2.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)
  const friendlyCurrency3 = n3.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)

  // Replace data in main file   
  headerMain.replaceText('{{Quotation}}', row[0].trim());
  // Replace general data in the body
  bodyMain.replaceText('{{Client}}', row[1].trim());
  bodyMain.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);

  // Replace table template values
  bodyTable.replaceText('{{Brand}}', row[2].trim());
  bodyTable.replaceText('{{Model}}', row[3].trim());
  bodyTable.replaceText('{{Year}}', row[4].trim());
  // I didn't include colors as im not sure what available colors are available
  // I didn't include availability as im not sure how to determine the availability

  // Replace financial data
  bodyTable.replaceText('{{Price}}', friendlyCurrency1);
  bodyTable.replaceText('{{Tax}}', friendlyCurrency2);
  bodyTable.replaceText('{{Final price}}', friendlyCurrency3);

  for(var i=0; i<bodyTable.getNumChildren();i++){ //run through the elements of the template doc's Body.
    switch (bodyTable.getChild(i).getType()) { //Deal with the various types of Elements we will encounter and append.
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        bodyMain.appendParagraph(bodyTable.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        bodyMain.appendListItem(bodyTable.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        bodyMain.appendTable(bodyTable.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
    }
  }

  // Delete after copying contents to main file
  docTable.saveAndClose();
  Drive.Files.remove(copyTable.getId());

  //Save and create Doc's URL
  docMain.saveAndClose();
  const url = docMain.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url);

  // Write tax and finalPrice
  var [[tax, finalPrice]] = sheet.getRange(index + 1, 8, 1, 2).getDisplayValues();

  if (tax != '') {
    tax += ',';
    finalPrice += ',';
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 8).setValue(tax + friendlyCurrency2);
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 9).setValue(finalPrice + friendlyCurrency3);
  }
  else {
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 8).setValue(friendlyCurrency2);
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 9).setValue(friendlyCurrency3);
  }
}

function convertDate(date) {
  var dateArray = date.split("/");
  return dateArray[1] + '/' + dateArray[0] + '/' + dateArray[2];
}

function formatPrice(price) {
  return Number(price.replace(/[$,]+/g,""));
}
```

#### Sheet Data:

[image: sheet1]

#### Folder:

[image: output2]

#### Sample File Generated:

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

#### Main template:

[image: main]

#### Table template:

[image: table]

#### NOTE!!:

- This recalculates your tax and final price
- I have separated the template into 2 parts, the main body, and the data per quotation so we can just loop into the table template and append to main everytime it finishes.
- Availability and colors were excluded due to uncertainty on to how I determine the values per quotation. Just add it depending on your needs.
- See comments for more information.